# Is derivative of a primary operator primary?

Tags: operators, differentiation, conformal-field-theory

For primary operators we have $$T(z)O(w)=\dfrac{hO(w)}{(z-w)^2} + \dfrac{\partial_wO(w)}{z-w}+\cdots$$

(the ordering problem can be ignored by setting $|z|>|w|$.)

If we apply $\partial_w$, then a $(z-w)^{-3}$ term appears, meaning that $\partial_wO(w)$ is not primary.

However, $\partial_w$ apparently transform like $\partial_w=\dfrac{\partial\bar w}{\partial w}\partial_{\bar w}$.

So what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

It's a trivial question, notice that $\partial_zO(z)\mapsto\partial_zO'(z)=\partial_z\left(\left(\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial z}\right)^{h}O(z)\right)$.

So there is a 2-order derivative, and $\partial_zO(z)$ is primary iff $h=0$.